# Filter Slide up img

Tags: html, css

I have an image on which I applied a filter in css so gray I would like this image to change to color by going up.

I would also like this animation to be done automatically

CSS :

```css
    img{ 
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: i don't undertand sorry, my image is gray and I would like it to change color from bottom to top

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a gradient layer on the top of the image and mix-blend-mode to create the grayscale effect then you animation its position to create the slide effect:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%;
  background:linear-gradient(black 45%,transparent 55%);
  mix-blend-mode:color;
  transition:1s;
}
.box:hover::after  {
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/108/200/200">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1068/200/200">
</div>
```

backdrop-filter can also do it:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter:grayscale(1);
  transition:1s;
}
.box:hover::after  {
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/108/200/200">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1068/200/200">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how can i run this animation automatically?

Comment: @Mcalan use keyframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: ok thanks, is there a solution to make my image even darker?

Comment: @Mcalan to the last solution you can add background, for example `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: I used background and I did not have the desired result
https://www.zupimages.net/up/21/04/p9nn.png

Comment: @Mcalan background to the pseudo element (and the second solution not the first)

Comment: @Mcalan that image is already very dark, no?

Comment: it gives me the same result
for me no

Comment: @Mcalan edit your question to make this requirement clear or if this part is an extra one no related to the initial quesiton, I advise you to ask another one. Comments won't be helpful to find the solution